# I can't escape the double quote character in javacc

Tags: java, regex, javacc

I'm using javacc to write a lexical analyzer and parser for a specified language. Strings in this language are defined as any combination of letters, digits and certain punctuation marks and are delimited by double quotes. I'm having difficulty delimiting the string with a double quote. For my string I have:

```
//Strings
TOKEN:
{
<STRING: ("\"")(["a"-"z","A"-"Z","0"-"9","+","-","*","/","%","+","<",">","
             (",")",",",";",":",".","?","!"," "])*("\"")>
```

The problem with this is that rather than accept a string like "hello", it accepts \"hello\".
I'm trying to escape the " character by using \" but it's just interpreting it literally as \". I've looked online and every example I've seen delimits a quote using "\"" the same I have and I can't find any other way to escape the character. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to get the parser to accept a string delimited by double quotes.

EDIT: I added JAVA_UNICODE_ESCAPE = true; to the start of my grammar file and it did absolutely nothing. The ONLY string the parser will accept is \"\". If I try to put anything in between those symbols like \"hi\" then I get an exception and something like "hi" just isn't accepted by the parser.

Comment: Hi, I saw that question before and it didn't help. The example uses "\"" as do I and I don't understand how it's working. Like I said above, it's the only option I've come across for delimiting strings but it just won't work in my case. It's delimiting them with an actual \" as opposed to a ".

Comment: Then you have something setup wrong. That is the method for escaping a character.

Comment: Do you have any idea what could be set up wrong? I've been searching for ages and I don't know why this is happening, I can't see reason why it should be behaving different for me then to everyone else.

Comment: http://media.tumblr.com/0b51b9ac044e062857f4d4a26effca1a/tumblr_inline_mhj9m5ZnPz1r2mqdf.gif honestly there are too many variables for me to give you a direct answer.

Comment: Can you post a link to your .jj file?  I'd like to take a look.

Comment: Also JAVA_UNICODE_ESCAPE refers to how your input file is processed, not how the .jj file is processed. Unless you are parsing Java, you probably don't want it set to true.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296318/how-to-use-backslash-escape-char-for-new-line-in-javacc , nor does the answer to that question answer this one.